# How to query versioned timeseries data for the latest version available

Tags: postgresql, time-series

I'm trying to write a postgres query against a versioned time-series table for the latest version of the data available.

I started out trying to take the latest version at each timestamp, but this gave me the problem that offsets of timestamps, or different collection frequencies, would interleave the versions together in the final result.  An example being the data interval is every two minutes, and is collected every minute.  Another example of different intervals is below.  I can accomplish this on the client side if I need to, but I think it'll be better if I can get it done on the SQL side.

This is my existing query with the interleaving problem.  It also isn't the most performant, but I can't see a way to push the CTE off to a view since the view won't have the date filter, which is very helpful on this table.

```sql
-- Current SQL query, not very fast
WITH version_ranked AS (
    SELECT
        tv.timeseries_id
        , tv.value_number
        , tv.value_time
        , tv.version_time
        , RANK() over (PARTITION BY tv.timeseries_id, tv.value_time ORDER BY tv.version_time DESC) AS rn
    FROM timeseries_values AS tv
      WHERE tv.timeseries_id = @id
        AND version_time > @time_filter
)
SELECT
    *
FROM version_ranked AS vr
WHEREv r.rn = 1
```

```
-- Sample table, with an extra row between versions
| timeseries_id (int) | value_number (numeric) | value_time (datetime) | version_time (datetime) |
|  1                  |    30                  | '2019-03-27 00:03:00' |  '2019-03-26 00:00:00'  |
|  1                  |    20                  | '2019-03-27 00:02:00' |  '2019-03-26 00:00:00'  |
|  1                  |    10                  | '2019-03-27 00:01:00' |  '2019-03-26 00:00:00'  |

|  1                  |    3                   | '2019-03-27 00:01:30' |  '2019-03-25 00:00:00'  |
|  1                  |    2                   | '2019-03-27 00:01:00' |  '2019-03-25 00:00:00'  |
|  1                  |    1                   | '2019-03-27 00:00:30' |  '2019-03-25 00:00:00'  |
```

```
-- What I get with above code, interleaving the versions
| timeseries_id (int) | value_number (numeric) | value_time (datetime) | version_time (datetime) |
|  1                  |    30                  | '2019-03-27 00:03:00' |  '2019-03-26 00:00:00'  |
|  1                  |    20                  | '2019-03-27 00:02:00' |  '2019-03-26 00:00:00'  |
|  1                  |    3                   | '2019-03-27 00:01:30' |  '2019-03-25 00:00:00'  |
|  1                  |    10                  | '2019-03-27 00:01:00' |  '2019-03-26 00:00:00'  |
|  1                  |    1                   | '2019-03-27 00:00:30' |  '2019-03-25 00:00:00'  |
```

```
--What I want in the end
| timeseries_id (int) | value_number (numeric) | value_time (datetime) | version_time (datetime) |
|  1                  |    30                  | '2019-03-27 00:03:00' |  '2019-03-26 00:00:00'  |
|  1                  |    20                  | '2019-03-27 00:02:00' |  '2019-03-26 00:00:00'  |
|  1                  |    10                  | '2019-03-27 00:01:00' |  '2019-03-26 00:00:00'  |
|  1                  |    1                   | '2019-03-27 00:00:30' |  '2019-03-25 00:00:00'  |
```

Comment: why "value_number"=3 does not appear on what you want?

Comment: Because it's from the previous version, and it's more valid to interpolate that value to 15 rather than take the old value of 3. It's a bit less obvious in this example, but alot of the use case here is predictions going forward several hours, and these predictions can vary quite a bit with new information from run to run. So the most recent version is the best source of truth from the first to the last timestamp in that version, but once it's outside that version, the previous one is the best source.

Comment: In the query, you have an ORDER BY tv.version_time DESC in the partition. For the desired output, just go ORDER BY value_time in the query. BTW, you do not need a CTE table here.

Comment: Using the query 


`SELECT
 tv.timeseries_id
 , tv.value_number
 , tv.value_time
 , tv.version_time
 , RANK() over (PARTITION BY tv.timeseries_id, tv.value_time ORDER BY tv.value_time) AS rn
FROM temp_table AS tv`


gives me everything at the same rank, so that doesn't give me the desired output.  If I got that wrong can you post the query that you mean?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I'll have to make use of the client side some and make two queries: one to get the max and min timestamps in a version, use the client to make a new query that's several simple SELECT UNION statements, and issue that.